# error 500 after upgrade to 1.9.2.4 from 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento-1, error, upgrade, http-error-500

After after upgrade to 1.9.2.4 from 1.9.2.3, I do not manage to get the site online. Any idea?

```
2016-03-05T04:01:14+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message '
'your host here' does not match the expected structure for a DNS hostname, 
'your host here' does not appear to be a valid URI hostname, 
'your host here' does not appear to be a valid local network name' 
in lib/Zend/Mail/Protocol/Abstract.php:145

Stack trace:

#17 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#18 app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}
```

I do not understad the errolog clearly

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using SMTP Pro or similar modules.

You just need to reconfigure them, do not know why it happened only after your Magento upgrade, but if you see the message it seems you still have placeholders (`your host here`) in your SMTP config.

Check your params is `System` > `Config` and everything will be working fine.